# $f:E \mapsto E$ is a mapping such that $f^{2} - f - id_{E} = 0$. Show $f$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to figure out if $f$ is an invertible function.

I was thinking about using two different approaches:

1- Assuming $f$ is invertible and solving $f^{2} - f - (f \circ f)$ to see if its equal to $0$.

2- Check if $f$ is a bijective function. Based on the definition of $f$, we have that $f(f(x)) - f(x) - id_{E} = 0 \Leftrightarrow  f(x) = f(f(x)) - id_{E}, \forall x \in E$

In both cases I feel like I'm missing information about $f$ to come to a conclusion...

Any hints?

EDIT: $E$ is a vector space.

Comment: $f(f-id) = id$.

Comment: I think we could use some details -- is $E$ a vector space? Is $f$ a linear transformation?

Comment: @Neal $E$ is a vector space, and $f$ is not specified as being a linear transformation. Just a transformation

Comment: @ArcticChar could you explain better?

Comment: No, I thought $f$ is linear. If it's not then my comment does not make sense.

Comment: Assuming $f$ is linear I still don't understand how you arrive to that conclusion

Comment: If $f$ is linear, then $f(f-I) = (f-I)f = I$, so $f-I$ is the inverse of $f$.

Comment: If $f$ is non-linear, then $(f-I)f = I$, so $f$ has a left inverse, and hence is injective.

Comment: If $f$ is injective and maps from $E$ to $E$ then we can assume that it is bijective right?

Comment: Regarding your last comment: this is why you want *linear* maps. There it is true (if $E$ is finite dimensional). For general mappings everything can happen. Let's look at the 1-dimensional vectorspace over $\mathbb{R}$, which we can easily identify with $\mathbb{R}$ itself. Now suppose that $g$ is the identity on all non-integer numbers and 'multiplication by 2' on the integers. Then $g$ is injective but not surjective. (I write $g$ instead of $f$ since $g$ does not satisfy the condition from the question.)

Comment: @Vincent I see... Then it must be a linear map and it is an error in the book.

Comment: @mozzarino Yes I think so too. In many books linear transformations are the only transformations that are discussed and hence the writers do not feel the need to repeat the adjective linear every time. That said it would be even nicer if we could find an example of a injective-not-surjective $f$ that *does* satisfy the requirement, just to sure that there is no secret superpower hidden in the equation that forces $f$ to be bijective after all.

Comment: O wait it DOES have such a superpower!

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith " $f(f−I)=(f−I)f=I$ so $f−I$ is the inverse of $f$." I can't find the proof of this property in my book, or even on google... Can you point me to somewhere I can read more about it?

Comment: From Stephen's $(f - I) \circ f = I$ we have that $f$ is injective, as he writes, but also that $f -  I$ is surjective. But if $f - I$ is surjective then so is $f$. It follows that $f$ is bijective after all.

Comment: $f$ has inverse $g$ if $fg = gf = I$. Now Stephen show's that in the linear case this is satisfied with $g = f - I$ so an inverse exists so it is invertible (existence of an inverse is what invertible means). To be clear: $I$ is the exact same thins as $id_E$.

Comment: @Vincent I see you guys writing about that property of function composition and the identity function, yet I don't really understand nor I can find anything about it anywhere...

Comment: @Vincent could you show me why $(f - I) \circ f = I$?

Comment: You mean the properties 'if $g \circ f$ is injective then $f$ is injective' and 'if $g \circ f$ is surjective then $g$ is surjective'? This is easy to prove yourself from the definition of injective and surjective: just imagine that the desired conclusion does *not* hold and check what the consequences are for the composition $g \circ f$.

Comment: @Vincent no, the property that if $f$ is a linear mapping then $(f - I) \circ f = I$

Comment: O right. Yes. First take any element $x$ in the vector space. Then $(f - I)(x) = f(x) - I(x) = f(x) - x$. This is the definition of the function $f - I$. Similar we would have $(f - g)(x) = f(x) - g(x)$. This is the *definition* of the difference of two functions.

Comment: Wait I'll type it as an answer because the system complains about 'extended discussions'

Comment: $(f-I)f = f^2 - f$.  This is just the definition of $f - I$, as @Vincent said.  No linearity needed for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll expand Stephen's answer in the comments.

Let's start at the beginning. Let $f$ and $g$ be two functions from $E$ to $E$. Then because $E$ allows addition and subtraction we can build a new function $f - g$ defined by $(f - g)(x) = f(x) - g(x)$. Here $x$ is any element of $E$.

$f$ need not be linear here. We apply the existence of this new function to the special case $g = I$, so we get the existence of a function $(f - I)$ that works as follows:

$(f - I)(x) = f(x) - x$

Now let $y$ be any element of $E$ and (this is the brilliant idea of Stephen) use the element $f(y)$ in place of $x$ above. Then we get:

$(f - I)(f(y)) = f(f(y)) - f(y)$

Now what do we recognize here? On the left hand side we just have $y$ fed into the composition $(f - I) \circ f$.
On the right hand side we have $(f \circ f)(y) - f(y)$ or $y$ fed into the function $(f \circ f) - f$.

So (since $y$ was arbitrary and had no special properties) we can dodge the $y$ and just write it as an equality of functions:

$(f - I) \circ f = (f \circ f) - f$

Aha! But we *know* something about the function on the right hand side. The question, as in the title of the post, stated that the function on the right hand side equals $I$! So we end up with:

$(f - I) \circ f = I$

As discussed in the comments this means that $f$ is injective and that $f - I$ is surjective.

EDIT: I mistakenly believed that this implies that $f$ must be surjective as well but my reasoning was faulty. The question of surjectivity of $f$ is still open. (EDIT 2: no it isn't. We can give examples of surjective $f$ and of non-surjective $f$. I will do so at the end of the post.)

HOWEVER, as pointed out by Stephen, when $f$ is linear we *do* know that $f$ is surjective because then we get a second equality

$f \circ (f - I) = I$.

I will explain that argument also.

Again let $y \in E$ be arbitarty and let $x = f(y)$. If we feed $y$ to the function on the left, so $f \circ (f - I)$ we get $f(x - y)$. Now if $f$ is linear this equals $f(x) - f(y)$. Remembering the definition of $x$ this can be written as $f(f(y)) - f(y)$ or $(f \circ f)(y) - f(y)$ or $(f \circ f - f)(y)$.

So again we can forget about $y$ and get the equality of functions:

$f \circ (f - I) = f \circ f - f$

But we know that the function on the right equals $I$ for this very special $f$ (this is given in the question) so that we end up with

$f \circ (f - I) = I$.

So summarizing: we always have that $f$ is injective. If $f$ is linear we moreover have that $f$ is surjective, hence bijective. The question if there exists a non-linear non-surjective $f$ nevertheless satisfying the equation from the title is quite interesting (see below) but (as stated in the comments) it seems most likely that your book was talking only about linear transformations.

EDIT 2: what if $f$ is not linear? To understand this we look at the case $E = \mathbb{R}$. Here there are exactly two *linear* functions $f$ (I will calle them $f_1$ and $f_2$) satisfying the requirement: $f_1$ is simply 'multiplying with $\phi$' and $f_2$ is 'multiplying with $-1/\phi$'. Here $\phi$ is the golden number. It satisfies $\phi(\phi - 1) = 1$, which is very similar to $f(f - I) = I$, this is why it works (I leave the details of verifying to you).

Now for non-linear functions.

Let $f$ be defined by $f(x) = f_1(x)$ if $|x| \geq 1$ and $f(x) = f_2(x)$ if $|x| < 1$. This still satisfies the equation, the point is that if $|x| \geq 1$ then $|f(x)| \geq 1$ and so $(f \circ f)(x) = (f_1 \circ f_1)(x)$ and we can use the fact that $f_1$ satisfies the criterion. And similarly if $|x| < 1$ then $|f(x)| < 1$ and hence $(f \circ f)(x) = (f_2 \circ f_2)(x)$. So in this case we know the equation holds because it holds for $f_2$.

Now my claim is that this $f$ is not surjective since $1$ is not in the image. Indeed: if $x \geq 1$ then $|f(x)| > 1.6$ so $f(x) \neq 1$ and if $x < 1$ then $|f(x)| < 1$ so $f(x) \neq 1$ as well.

FINALLY: this example shows that we *need* some extra condition (of which linearity is the most natural) to get surjectivity. It does *not* mean that the linearity is the only such condition, i.e. that bijective $f$ satisfying the condition of the question are automatically linear. Here is an example of a *bijective non-linear* $f$.

Let $f(x) = f_1(x)$ for $x \in \ldots \phi^{-2}, \phi^{-1}, 1, \phi^{1}, \phi^2, \ldots$ (i.e. all powers of $\phi$) and $f(x) = f_2(x)$ for all other $x \in E = \mathbb{R}$. Then again we have that $f$ behaves as $f_1$ on $f(x)$ if $f$ behaves as $f_1$ on $x$ and that $f$ behaves as $f_2$ on $f(x)$ whenever $f$ behaves as $f_2$ on $x$. So again we see that $f$ satisfies the condition of the question just because the linear maps $f_1$ and $f_2$ do. However $f$ is not linear itself as $f(1) + f(2) \neq f(3)$.

Comment: There is a small typo in your (now deleted) comment $f^2(y) - f(y) = I$ must be $f^2(y) - f(y) = I(y)$, or shorter $f^2(y) - f(y) = y$. But with that fixed the answer is that you are absolutely right, this only holds if $f^2(y) - f(y) = I(y)$. BUT! We KNOW that $f^2(y) - f(y) = I(y)$ for all $y$ because the question TOLD us that for THIS VERY SPECIAL MAP $f$ (so not just any map $f$) we have that $f^2 - f = I$.

Comment: The fact we know it from the original question was the reason I deleted... I was so entangled in the explanation that I totally forgot that.

Thanks alot for the very detailed explanation. I really wished more people would have the patience to help as you just did!

Comment: How do you argue that the surjectivity of $f - I$ implies the surjectivity of $f$? Barring trivial spaces, $0$ isn't surjective, but $0 - I$ is. Of course $0$ doesn't satisfy $f^2 - f = I$, maybe that yields the surjectivity without linearity. (But I'm rather convinced that $f$ was intended to be linear.)

Comment: @DanielFischer I started typing an answer and then realized that I made a mistake. I'll edit the answer!